# Conceptual question: how can we extract specific values that fall under multiple conditions using SQL?

Tags: sql, r

I am trying to understand how to derive a percentage of values that specifically fall within multiple categories from more than two tables. For example, given a sample scenario where only a small number of adults who caught the flu died. How do you find a percentage of adults with flu that died and a percentage of adults with flu that didn't die?

There are a total of three tables pasted below for your reference. The first table has a list of people that indicate general information about the person, such as name, age, income, etc. The second table has a list of people that indicate a variety of people's illnesses, such as being sick from the flu. The last table indicates a list of people who have died and their cause of death.

How can one derive the desired output using SQL? One can also use a combination of R functions (such as merge function) as the SQL code would be run in an R environment.

Sample Table 1

```
Name   Age   Gender
Andrew 25    Male
Lisa   21    Female
Conor  35    Male
John   51    Male
Linda  29    Female
```

Sample Table 2

```
Name    Illness
Andrew  Flu
Conor   Flu
Lisa    Flu
John    Smallpox
```

Sample Table 3

```
Name    Cause of Death
Andrew  Flu
```

Desired Output

```
Fatality(Death from Flu)   Percentage of people with flu
Yes                        1/3
No                         2/3
```

Comment: Please can catch the flu more than once.  How are they handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN SQL (only)

assuming you joined  your table using left (for include not matching  rows  between tables) and remap the cause_of_death using a case when

```
select  t1.Name, t1.Age, t1.Gender, t2.Illness
 , case when t3.cause_of_death ='Flu' then 'Yes' else 'Not' END Fatality_death_from_flu
from table1 t1
INNER join table2 t2 on t1.name  = t2.name 
  AND t2.Illness ='Flu'
left join table3 t3 on t1.name  = t3.name
```

you could get the totale numbers of rows  using

```
select count(*) from  (
  select  t1.Name, t1.Age, t1.Gender, t2.Illness
   , case when t3.cause_of_death ='Flu' then 'Yes' else 'Not' END Fatality_death_from_flu
  from table1 t1
  INNER join table2 t2 on t1.name  = t2.name 
    AND t2.Illness ='Flu'
  left join table3 t3 on t1.name  = t3.name 
) tt1
```

and the numer for yes and not  using

```
select Fatality_death_from_flu,  count(*) from  (
  select  t1.Name, t1.Age, t1.Gender, t2.Illness
   , case when t3.cause_of_death ='Flu' then 'Yes' else 'Not' END Fatality_death_from_flu
  from table1 t1
  INNER join table2 t2 on t1.name  = t2.name 
    AND t2.Illness ='Flu'
  left join table3 t3 on t1.name  = t3.name 
) tt2
```

combining the query you could obatin the desired  result using

```
  select r1.Fatality_death_from_flu, r1.count_fatality/r22.count_tot
  from  (
      select Fatality_death_from_flu,  count(*)  count_fatality from  (
        select  t1.Name, t1.Age, t1.Gender, t2.Illness
         , case when t3.cause_of_death ='Flu' then 'Yes' else 'Not' END Fatality_death_from_flu
        from table1 t1
        INNER join table2 t2 on t1.name  = t2.name 
          AND t2.Illness ='Flu'
        left join table3 t3 on t1.name  = t3.name 
      ) tt2 
  ) r1
  CROSS JOIN  (
    select count(*)  count_tot 
    from  (
        select  t1.Name, t1.Age, t1.Gender, t2.Illness
         , case when t3.cause_of_death ='Flu' then 'Yes' else 'Not' END Fatality_death_from_flu
        from table1 t1
        INNER join table2 t2 on t1.name  = t2.name 
          AND t2.Illness ='Flu'
        left join table3 t3 on t1.name  = t3.name 
      ) tt1

  ) r2
```

But using some of the intermediate query you can easiy use  R for obatin the desired  result

Answer (score 0):

Table1 doesn't seem necessary.

This seems more reasonable to put into columns than rows:

```
select count(*) as num_people,
       sum(case when t3 is null then 1 else 0 end) as not_died,
       sum(case when t3 is not null then 1 else 0 end) as died,
       avg(case when t3 is null then 1.0 else 0 end) as not_died_ratio,
       avg(case when t3 is not null then 1.0 else 0 end) as died_ratio
from table2 t2 left join
     table3 t3
     on t3.name = t2.name and
        t3.illness = 'Flu'
where t2.cause_of_death = 'Flu'
```